# HTML TABLE <TH> is by default text font-color white / invisible on 100% zoom in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-table, zooming

Code is basic HTML 4 table code.

```
<th colspan="6">
             Click on a category below to view all available items. 
</th>
```

It's not a CSS issue as I don't use any CSS. Setting a CSS style color to anything other than the default fixes the issue but that's not what I am trying to find out because we can clearly see that at 90% zoom the text color is black which is default and it works fine. Also it works good in internet explorer but its messed up in chrome.

**Chrome Version: Version 43.0.2357.130 m**
**Source page:**
[www.HighGamer.com/itemshop](http://www.HighGamer.com/itemshop)

90% zoom on chrome.

[image: 1]

100% zoom on chrome.

[image: 2]

Comment: Can not reproduce this, same chrome version on windows 7.

Comment: FWIW works fine for me in  44.0.2403.61 beta-m (64-bit) / Win7 - Try launching chrome w/ `--disable-extensions`

Comment: @Alex K. That works, fixed the problem but I wonder what extension could be causing it.

Comment: @AlexK. After running chrome with **--disable-extentions** then running it again normally the problem has been solved and I can't reproduce it anymore despite all of my original extensions and plugins being enabled. Seems like it was some kind of a random internal glitch that was cleared up by relaunching chrome with that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running chrome with --disable-extentions then running it again normally the problem has been solved and I can't reproduce it anymore despite all of my original extensions and plugins being enabled. Seems like it was some kind of a random internal glitch that was cleared up by relaunching chrome with that parameter.